# get results from couchdb design doc

Tags: couchdb, view

Learning Couchdb, but I can't work out how to use views. I have created this design doc, that works well in futon, but I can't work out from the Couchdb documentation or the definitive guide, I'm sure it's there, but I can't find how you actually get the results of this design doc using the command line

```
function(doc) {
if(doc.event && doc.form) {
  emit(doc.event, doc.form);
  }
}
```

this produces three names in my test database currently and works in futon, but I can't find a way to get it from the command line, how is this done please.

Comment: By command line, you mean cURL?

Comment: Are you sure you've read the documentation? Here's an [intro to views](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/couchapp/views/intro.html) and the necessary [HTTP API](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/api/ddoc/views.html) to retrieve your view results.

Comment: What is the name of the view? and of the design doc?